# How to classify image when training samples are a mix of proportions? (plant cover)

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have some multispectral images (RGB + NIR) that I would like to classify for vegetation type using a supervised classification algorithm (most likely random forest but I'm also going to look into SVM and artificial neutral networks). The training data that I have are quadrats describing percent vegetation cover, and there are 15 vegetation options. For instance, a very fake example could be:

```
Plot 1
Oak = 50%
Alder = 20%
Maple = 30%
Blackberry = 0%
English ivy = 0%
... etc


Plot 2
Blackberry = 30%
Grass = 50%
Bare earth = 20%
Oak = 0%
... etc
```

My issue is that I am not familiar with ML classification except using random forest with defined categories for the dependent variable. Barring making categories out of similar groups of proportions (so anything that is a certain mix of grass and bare each is just called "grass"), is there another way to model this so that  I can use these samples to classify the rest of the images? (Note: I have tried searching a lot and I think I may simply be missing a critical piece of jargon to Google.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I was too quick to post a question because I just found the phrase I was looking for: **fuzzy classification**. Apparently what I have are "mixed pixels" because they belong to two or more categories, and there are many papers about how to use [artificial neural networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d55/6ad84caee66a6e491de150f24417ec984f48.pdf) and [support vector machines](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/09a4/166399ac8d81873bd3b17c8cd609162feeed.pdf) to classify these pixels effectively. There's also a really good overview of the topic in general in [this paper](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/part7/PDF/212.pdf). I did not seen much on using random forest for fuzzy classification.

(Question not deleted in the hopes that others may find this useful in their searches)